# direct path read error in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

When an User execute a task then  application ( Desktop App ) does not response to at least ten minute wait for output.
And then I see an Event in  v$session view which give me event name "DIRECT PATH READ".

Comment: "DIRECT PATH READ" means that the session is reading data from from datafile into PGA(sessions private area). Most probably it is filling some hash table. Without knowing the exec execution plan, you can not investigate the problem.

Comment: The first thing to do would be to find out what the application is doing during that ten minute wait.